# AmazonEventBridgeClient.PutEventsAsync returns status code OK even when event bus name provided doesn't exists

Tags: c#, .net, aws-event-bridge

1. I instantiate AmazonEventBridgeClient class provide a region.
2. I then instantiate PutEventsRequestEntry object, I set EventBusName to a name that doesn't exists.
3. When I call PutEventsAsync method against AmazonEventBridgeClient  instance, it returns a HttpStatusCode of OK.
   I was expecting to get some error indicating that the even bus name doesn't exists. Am I missing anything? Is there any API to do the validation of event bus name exists?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently this is the known behavior, i.e., sending events to a non-existing event bus won't throw an error/exception. Feel free to reach out to your AWS representative to file a feature request if desired.

Comment: What's the best practice in that case then?

Comment: If you want to make sure an event is delivered to a target you need to implement custom (target) logic. We are working on logging improvements so you can see the flow of an event through EventBridge, similar to what's available in Pipes (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-logging-support-for-amazon-eventbridge-pipes/). 

There's not really a best practice to ensure the target event bus always exists since it could be deleted any time so there's no guarantee it will exist when you publish. Generally, automation like Terraform/CDK can help to ensure correct spelling.